Weird first layer ridges
The first layer has these weird ridges.
Before the print I cleaned the bed with IPA. There is an ABL and the rest of the layers come out fine.
I tried 2 surfaces Gerolite and PEI (in the photo).
I could use some advice to get a clean first layer.



Looking at the skirt and the overall quality it appears that your nozzle is too close to the bed, increase the initial distance between the nozzle and the bed by increasing the Z-offset of your probe defined by M851 or through the graphical display.
See this answer for more information on the Z-offset. Furthermore, your build surface doesn't seem to be straight, you might benefit from a more dense grid to scan your surface or use UBL (see question What is ABL or UBL? Is this the same?.
